# position absolute with height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with displaying a div. For some reason it is not displaying the inner div.

The position of parent div is relative where as the child div is absolute.

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6R3Hr/6/

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="page-center">
  <div class="question_slide inidfeedback">Test</div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code :**

```
.question_slide {
  background: #000000;
  height: 569px;
  width:100%
}

.question_slide {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.page-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of using `position:relative` on page-center?

Comment: Otherwise overflow hidden doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just interchange their positions.

```
.question_slide {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.page-center {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1100px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a demo:http://jsfiddle.net/6R3Hr/3/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If overflow:hidden is a must, then you must specify a height for your relative div:

```
.page-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100px;
}
```

Just choose how much height will work for you.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Waclock/6R3Hr/8/)'s a working jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: Actually if I remove overflow hidden then my other stuffs is going to be a mess. Isn't it possible to fix it without removing overflow hidden.

Comment: In that case I suppose you will have to give your relative div a height.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a height style.  Since the only content is relatively positioned, it doesn't have any inherent height value and because the overflow is hidden, it's not onscreen.

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/6R3Hr/2/

```
.page-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height:20px;
}
```